# Laravel dependancy injection for views

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to get the hang of dependancy injection and the IoC container in Laravel.

Currently I have a class full of static methods that I use in my views. E.g.

```
class Templatizer {
    /**
     * Generates a colored FontAwsome check or cross from a true/false argument
     * @param  boolean $bool 
     * @return string       The HTML markup of the icon
     */
    public static function boolicon($bool)
    {
        return $bool ? '<span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>' : '<span class="fa fa-times text-danger"></span>';
    }
}
```

I have composer autoload the class and in my view I can just go `{{ Templatizer::boolicon($trueOrFalseValue) }}`.

Clearly this is bad practice and I'd like to move away from using static methods. I presume the correct way is to inject an *instance* of `Templatizer` and use the methods something like {{ $templatizer->boolicon($v) }}`.

How would I structure this? Presumably I'd need to inject an instance of `Templatizer` into my controller via the constructor? e.g.

```
class PagesController extends BaseController {

    protected $templatizer;

    public function __construct(Templatizer $templatizer)
    {
        $this->templatizer = $templatizer;
    }
}
```

And then for, say, the method for the index page I pass the instance to the view? e.g.

```
# inside PagesController
public function index()
{
    return View::make('pages.index', ['templatizer' => $this->templatizer]);
}
```

If this is correct, where is an appropriate place to put my `Templatizer` class? How would I bind it to the IoC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't see anything wrong with calling these methods statically. It looks like this is just a HTML helper class of your own and you should be fine.

If you decide to go with Dependency Injection the "correct" way to register your class would be using [Service Providers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers).

Assigning it to the views the way you wrote would work but you can also get it once you need it this way:

```
$templatizer = App::make('Yournamespace\Templatizer');
```

And finally probably the best solution in your case would be building your own [Facade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#creating-facades).

Comment: Actually I think you make a good point regarding the fact that these are all static methods and can be used as they are. E.g. the `Illuminate\Str` class that comes with Laravel works in the same way. My question could still apply to other situations however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should inject it via the controller constructor, the files can live anywhere you like as long as they are autoloaded in.

I like to create a folder in the root directory called `src` so that my composer.json file looks like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ....
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Foo\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Then you can have src/Templatizer.php which would look like:

```
<?php namespace Foo;

class Templatizer {

}
```

Now you just need a service provider to bind your instance of Templatizer (this basically makes Laravel aware of your class and allows you to inject it into your controllers) in src/FooServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Foo;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FooServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Register the service provider
     */
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('Foo\Templatizer', function($app) {
            return new Templatizer();
        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `Foo\FooServiceProvider` to the `providers` array in app config and you should be all set to do...

```
public function __construct(Foo\Templatizer $templatizer) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also create instance on BaseController.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    var $templatizer;
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
            $templatizer = new \Templatizer();
            View::share('templatizer', $templatizer);
        }
    }

}
```

use this `$templatizer` instance in a all view. 
something like {{ $templatizer->boolicon($v) }}`.